# How do you set FontFamily in C# winforms Control (e.g. TextBox) from a html/css style string (ie: Futura,Verdana,Arial)

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

Is there a way to set the font of a Windows Forms Control in C# that will accept a comma separated list of fonts?  I want something similar to how browsers interpret CSS font families where it goes down the list until it finds the first font installed on the computer.

Example:

```
string fontList = "Obscure Font1, Obscure Font2, Verdana"
textBox1.Font = new Font( FontFamilyFromHtml(fontList), FontStyle.Bold);
```

Is there anything built in to .NET or do you need to create a method that will split the string on commas, then test the installed font list for each one until a match is found?

Comment: new FontFamily() throws exceptions

Comment: @MitchWheat - Please reopen so I can post a solution.

Comment: In what way is this "ambiguous, vague, incomplete"? It can clearly be answered with "Yes, here's how (...example...)" or "No."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out of the box API call, so you will have to split the string and search through the installed fonts.

Here is an implementation that uses the [InstalledFontCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.installedfontcollection.aspx) to do just that:

```
private FontFamily FindFontByCSSNames(string cssNames)
{
    string[] names = cssNames.Split(',');
    System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection installedFonts = new System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection();
    foreach (var name in names)
    {

        var matchedFonts = from ff in installedFonts.Families where ff.Name == name.Trim() select ff;

        if (matchedFonts.Count() > 0)
            return matchedFonts.First();
    }

    // No match, return a default
    return new FontFamily("Arial");
}
```